# Implement a class want to simulate std::string but get stuck when push_back it into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, move-semantics, push-back

I have implemented a class String. When I push_back a String object to a Vector, the program gets stuck. Please help me review it if you're interested.

String.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class String {
public:
   String();
   String(const char *);
   String(const String &);
   String(const std::string &);
   String(String &&) noexcept;
   String &operator=(String &&) noexcept;
   ~String();
   String &operator=(const String &);
   std::string to_string() const;

   friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, String s);

private:
   std::pair<char *, char *>
      alloc_n_copy(char *, char *);
   void free();
   static std::allocator<char> alloc;
   char *beg;
   char *end;
   size_t length;
};
```

String.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstring>
#include "String.h"

std::allocator<char> String::alloc = std::allocator<char>();

String::String()
   : beg(nullptr), end(nullptr), length(0) {}

String::String(const char *ptr) {
   std::cout << "Const char constructor execute" << std::endl;
   const char *tmp = ptr;
   while (*tmp++ != '\0') ++length;
   beg = alloc.allocate(length);
   end = std::uninitialized_copy(ptr, tmp, beg);
}

String::String(const std::string &s) {
   std::cout << "Const string constructor execute" << std::endl;
   strcpy_s(beg, s.size(), s.c_str());
   length = s.size();
   char *tmp = beg;
   end = tmp + length;
}

String::String(const String &s) {
   std::cout << "Copy constructor execute" << std::endl;
   beg = alloc.allocate(s.length);
   end = std::uninitialized_copy(s.beg, s.end, beg);
}

std::pair<char *, char *>
String::alloc_n_copy(char *beg, char *end) {
   auto newBeg = alloc.allocate(end - beg);
   return{ newBeg, std::uninitialized_copy(beg, end, newBeg) };
}

String &String::operator=(const String &s) {
   length = s.length;
   auto newStr = alloc_n_copy(s.beg, s.end);
   free();
   beg = newStr.first;
   end = newStr.second;
   return *this;
}

String::String(String &&s) noexcept : beg(s.beg), end(s.end), length(s.length) {
   std::cout << "Move constructor execute" << std::endl;
   s.beg = s.end = nullptr;
   s.length = 0;
}

String &String::operator=(String &&s) noexcept {
   if (this != &s) {
      beg = s.beg;
      end = s.end;
      length = s.length;
      s.beg = s.end = nullptr;
      s.length = 0;
   }
   return *this;
}

void String::free() {
   while (length-- >= 0) {
      alloc.destroy(end--);
   }
   alloc.deallocate(beg, length);
}

String::~String() {
   free();
}

std::string String::to_string() const {
   std::string s(beg);
   return s;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, String s) {
   std::string str(s.beg);
   os << str;
   return os;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
   vector<String> v;
   String s1("abc");
   String s2("def");

   v.push_back(s1);
   v.push_back(s2);

   return 0;
}
```

result:

```html
Const char constructor execute
Const char constructor execute
Copy constructor execute
Move constructor execute
```

I don't know why the second push_back is a move construction.

And when the push_back finished, the program can't exit. Is there any resource failed to release?

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend running the program with an address sanitizer.

Comment: `Operator =` is broken if self-assignment is done.  It is also broken if the memory allocation fails.  Use `copy / swap` instead of rewriting your copy constructor and destructor inside of your assignment operator.

Comment: Look at your move assignment operator.  What do you do if your object already has data in it?

Comment: `String::String(const std::string &s)` is broken; `strcpy_s(beg, s.size(), s.c_str());` tries to copy to an initialised `beg` also no space is allocated for the copy.

Comment: Your assignment operator should look like this:  `String& operator=(String) noexcept;` and do a `swap` (which you also need to define as a friend function, so ADL works).  With modern C++, you shouldn't have a `String const&` and `String&&` parameter assignment operators.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your program blocks is because your destructor never terminates:

> ```
> void String::free() {
>    while (length-- >= 0) {
>       alloc.destroy(--end);
>    }
>    alloc.deallocate(beg, length);
> }
> ```

Since `length` is an unsigned type, `length >= 0` is always true.  You probably don't want to be decrementing `length` here, before it's used as argument to `alloc.deallocate()`.  I suggest:

```
void String::free() {
   while (end > beg) {
      alloc.destroy(end--);
   }
   alloc.deallocate(beg, length);
}
```

---

There are other bugs, such as failing to initialise `length` before using it in the `char const*` constructor (I don't see why you don't just use `std::strlen()`) and failing to allocate in the `std::string` constructor.  I recommend using a good set of warnings (I used `g++ -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds  -Weffc++`) and addressing them all.  The problem above was identified very easily this way.

After compiling clear of warnings, then run your code under Valgrind or other memory checker to understand some of the outstanding issues.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will follow it.

Comment: It should be while( beg >= end) Right?

Comment: I haven't tested that code properly - I think it should be `beg < end` as it is, but we should be passing `--end` to `destroy()`, given that `end` points *after* the last element.  As I said, you still have a few more bugs to find (and plenty of hints in comments to the question).

Comment: Ok, I get it. The end is after the last element.